# resizing linux partition

Tags: linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [resizing partitions with gparted](https://superuser.com/questions/21164/resizing-partitions-with-gparted)

Hello,

Can any one suggest tools for resizing linux partitions under RHEL 5.5. ALSO what precaution we can take before resizing the partitions.

Comment: Use [gparted ](http://superuser.com/questions/21164/resizing-partitions-with-gparted)

Comment: As for precautions, backup *all* your data…twice.

Answer (score 0):

LVM is king...if you eventually need to resize/add to partitions LVM is built for this...just a thought.  lvresize lets you change partition sizes.  If you want something to resize a partition regardless of format, than partition tools are what you are looking for, but if you want the BEST plan...use LVM to manage your partitions and you can add, change, resize at will.  Just my thoughts....it's a loaded question