# How to reshuffled disk partitions in place?

Tags: partitioning

Linux was installed on partitions 5 and 6 because 1-4 were taken by something else.

Partitions 1-4 were deleted, and there's some space in front of partition 5 now.

Is there a way to move contents from partitions 5 and 6 to the beginning of the disk using some tool?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [resizing partitions with gparted](https://superuser.com/questions/21164/resizing-partitions-with-gparted)

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck? Show us your research.

Answer (score 1):

Given you have never partitioned before a full backup is advised just in case.

Gparted is a free partitioning tool you can place on USB drive via rufus or etc.
Boot from it and move partitions around.

Comment: Full, continuous backup is always a good idea, not only before risky operations and not only if you're inexperienced. Experts' drives also die without warning sometimes.